# Remove spaces from matched patterns using re.sub()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to remove spaces form matched pattern using `re.sub()`

My text will be something such as:

`text = Hi my name is Bob and I am taking courses ABC 123 and EFG123`

Now my intention is to find courses, and remove the spaces between them.

My regex pattern is:

`regex = '[a-zA-Z]{2,4}[ ]?\d{2,4}'`

I am trying to remove the space in `ABC 123` , currently I am using:

```
text = re.sub(r'[a-zA-Z]{2,4}[ ]?\d{2,4}', '\\1\\2', text)
```

However, I get the error:

```
error: invalid group reference 1 at position 1
```

How can I remove that space there, I have try replacing the whole thing with a single space and I can confirm the regex does find the pattern, however, I get the following error.

Comment: Groups are marked by `(...)`. You didnot mark any groups in your regex pattern. [`Python Docs: Regular Expression HOWTO- Grouping`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#grouping)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
text = "Hi my name is Bob and I am taking courses ABC 123 and EFG123"
>>> re.sub(r'([A-z]{2,4})\W?(\d{2,4})', '\\1\\2', text)
'Hi my name is Bob and I am taking courses ABC123 and EFG123'
```

You didn't specify the capturing groups (`([A-z]{2,4})` and `(\d{2,4})`) in your regex pattern, hence the error.